# Apache2 child process and client connection

Tags: apache-2.2

I have some doubt related to apache child process and client connection.

1, In my server 100 apache2 child process are running, does it mean that 100 client are connected the server?

2, I have set Maxclient 200, what happens when more than 200 client try to connect to the server for long time?

I am asking this questing because, one day my web server is not responding. I have restarted the server the it work fine. Then I checked the history of process from the zabbix, it show that 256 apache process are running for 7hr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server 100 apache process running , it means that 100 client are connected to the server.

The MaxClients directive sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be served. Any connection attempts over the MaxClients limit will normally be queued, up to a number based on the ListenBacklog directive. Once a child process is freed at the end of a different request, the connection will then be serviced.

The MaxRequestsPerChild directive sets the limit on the number of requests that an individual child server process will handle. After MaxRequestsPerChild requests, the child process will die. If MaxRequestsPerChild is 0, then the process will never expire.

For more information :

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html